# Do Trinitarians believe that the saints become angels upon the resurrection?

Tags: angels, predestination, kingdom-of-heaven, transfiguration, adoption

I have a question pertaining to Hebrews 12:22-23, which says:

> “But you have come to Mount Zion, to the city of the living God, the
> heavenly Jerusalem. You have come to myriads of angels in joyful
> assembly, to the congregation of the firstborn, enrolled in heaven.
> You have come to God the Judge of all, and to the spirits of the
> righteous made perfect.”

Are the myriads of angels the “congregation of the firstborn enrolled in heaven” and the “spirits of the righteous made perfect”? Is this saying that the chosen of God become angels?

Jesus said in Mark 12:25,

> “When the dead rise, they will neither marry nor be given in marriage.
> Instead, they will be like the angels in heaven.”

We see here that Jesus declares that we will be “like the angels”.

Romans 8:19 says,

> “The creation waits in eager expectation for the revealing of the sons
> of God.”

Here again, Paul said that the chosen of God are adopted as sons of God; a title shared by angels.

Along with the belief that Jesus is the Chief Angel of God, and those who believe in him will become “just as he is” in glorified composition, does Hebrews 12:22-23 thus imply that believers become sons of God (angels) just as Jesus is the Son of God?

Comment: You claim that "Jesus is the Chief Angel of God" but that view is denounced by trinitarians. Trinitarians know that the pre-incarnate Jesus was never created as an angel.  Read Hebrews chapter 1. The trinitarian answer to your main question is a resounding NO.

Comment: The Scriptures say that we will judge angels under the authority of Christ.  He is better than... higher than.

Comment: @MikeBorden, that is, judging the fallen angels?

Comment: @JoshuaB I do not believe this is limited to either penal judgement or fallen angels.

Comment: Hello Menorahman , It's Timothy we need to talk please. Find me on Google private chat bar

Comment: @FewAgainstMany-Israel I just reached you on the chat bar. God bless.

Comment: God bless you abundantly and thanks for replying

Answer (score 3):

**The Question**

**Are the myriads of angels the “congregation of the firstborn enrolled in heaven” and the “spirits of the righteous made perfect”? Is this saying that the chosen of God become angels?**

---

Trinitarians would say 'No' to this question.

The statements made in the question are contrary to the scripture in two regards :

- Jesus states (as reported by Mark) that the resurrected in Christ are 'like' angels *only in this respect* - that they neither marry nor are given in marriage.
- John tells us (who believe) that '*Now* (not later) are we the sons of God,' 1 John 3:2, through repentance and faith in Christ.

---

The header question asks about 'Trinitarian' belief but the body of the question assumes a patently non-Trinitarian statement namely 'the belief that Jesus is the Chief Angel of God'.

The question thus becomes somewhat clouded in its underlying purpose but I have answered as the question apparently invites.